# How to boot from CD?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, compact-disc

On any other computer I would just pop in the cd, restart the computer and wait for the "press any key to boot from cd" prompt at start up.

The problem is, on this desktop I have I never get this prompt. This desktop also never came with a BIOS. So every time I start it up, the window stays blank for a minute and suddenly loads the OS which is Ubuntu.

Can someone please help me. I need to install Windows 7 and can't figure out how to boot from CD.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of motherboard or computer?

That would help greatly, but here are some general suggestions:

Hit F12, F11 or F10 at boot up.  Try each one on its own... turn the PC on and hold the key until it starts to beep, and then release, and hit intermittantly.  This may cause a "Boot Menu" to appear.

If not that, try F1, F2, or DEL.  That will get a BIOS screen to appear, where you can change the boot order.

Hope this helps,

Glenn